# Как получить IMEI в Android?

Tags: android, android-sdk, imei

Как получить IMEI устройства?
Есть две функции:

- getImei()
- getDeviceId()

Какую из них правильнее использовать?
Как получить IMEI на Android 10 (SDK 29)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для конфиденциальности пользователей, Google не рекомендует использовать аппаратные идентификаторы устройства. Такие как:

- IMEI
- Serial Number
- MAC-address (WiFi, Bluetooth)

Так же не рекомендуется использовать программный SSAID (Android ID).

Для получения IMEI необходимо разрешение `READ_PHONE_STATE`, а с **Android 10** (SDK 29), теперь необходимо разрешение `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE`, которое доступно только системным приложениям.

**Получается, c SDK 29, для не системных приложений, больше нет легального способа получить IMEI.**

Данный метод вернет **IMEI** если это возможно, иначе `null`:

```
@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
public static String getImei(Context context) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        return null; //Доступен только системным приложениям
    } else {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return null; //Нет доступа к звонилке
        }
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) Application.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(telephonyManager == null) {
            return null; //Нет звонилки
        }
        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                return telephonyManager.getImei();
            } else {
                return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Device", "Failed to get IMEI.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал Максим для идентификации устройства не рекомендуется использовать IMEI. Но возможно вам пригодится данное решение, оно позволяет создать идентификатор устройства, но я не гарантирую его уникальность и повторяемость. Возможно это направит вас на лучшее решение.

```kotlin
object UniqueId {

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    fun generate(): String {

        val abisLength: Int
        abisLength = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val abis = StringBuilder()
            for (abi in Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS) {
                abis.append(abi)
            }
            abis.toString().length
        } else {
            Build.CPU_ABI.length
        }

        val devIdShort = "35" + Build.BOARD.length % 10 + Build.BRAND.length % 10 +
            abisLength % 10 + Build.DEVICE.length % 10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length % 10 +
            Build.MODEL.length % 10 + Build.PRODUCT.length % 10
        val serial = try {
            "${android.os.Build::class.java.getField("SERIAL").get(null)}"
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            "serial"
        }

        return UUID(devIdShort.hashCode().toLong(), serial.hashCode().toLong()).toString()
    }
}
```